# Why does graphql not inject my data into react component prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am using this [tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/) to create a gatsby blog that will use Markdown pages.

I am trying to create a 'post-repeater' component that will loop through all my posts and create links to them using frontmatter that looks like this.

```
---
path: "/blog/my-first-post"
date: "2019-05-04"
title: "My first blog post"
---
```

I have a graphQl query that is correctly pulling the data.

[image: graphQl query]

My component looks like this.

```
import React from "react"

import "../styles/post-repeater.scss"
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby"

export default function PostRepeater({postQuery}){
    console.log('my data:',postQuery);
    return(

        <>
            {postQuery.map(instance => 
                <div className="post">
                    <h2>{instance.title}</h2>
                    <span className="datePosted">{instance.date}</span>
                    <span className="readTime"></span>
                    <p></p>
                    <Link to={instance.path}>Read More</Link>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            )}
        </>

    )
}

export const postQuery = graphql`
query MyQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            path
            title
            date
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

If I put a console.log of postQuery from inside the PostRepeater component, it comes back as undefined. So it appears that the component is never getting the data even though I followed the same layout from the tutorial above.

If I put a `console.log('data', postQuery);` from outside the component, I get the following in the console.

> data 2575425095

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try StaticQuery https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/

Comment: Try making a producible example, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you have a gatsby template here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default

Comment: I uploaded it to netlify. I tried to create a minimal reproducible example but I can't get the allMarkdownRemark plugin to work on codesandbox. Here's the url anyway. https://codesandbox.io/embed/gatsby-starter-default-prifj

Here is the URL to the netlify instance https://hopeful-shirley-490d3a.netlify.com/

I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 2):

After making a query `gatsby` injects it as an object matching the query.

In your case, as you see in `GraphiQL` you get an object with the initial key `data`.

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMarkdownRemark": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "frontmatter": {
              "title": "...",
              "date": ...
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What you tried to do, is [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) **a not existing key `postQuery`**.

Moreover, you still can log it outside of the component scope as the value exported from `export const postQuery`

```
export const postQuery = graphql`
  query MyQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            path
            title
            date
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

//       v  Logs the query id
console.log('my data:', postQuery);

//                                               v Is not defined
export default function PostRepeater({ data, postQuery }) {

  //                       v Shadowing the outter value of postQuery
  console.log('my data:', postQuery);

  // The query injected as "data" object
  console.log('my data:', data);

  return (
    <>
      //      v Be aware of which object you query, edges is an array
      {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(...)}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why but both of my logs inside the PostRepeater component are returning as undefined whereas the log outside the component does display the ID like you wrote above.

Comment: It explained in the answer, which part you didnt understand?

Comment: Also it depends on your structure, there are differences between page query and static query, make sure you follow the docs

Comment: Maybe I just need to read the docs more. But I literally copy and pasted your answer into my component and it didn't work. The two console logs inside the PostRepeater component return as undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The export of graphql queries which gets automatically attached to props only work for page components. For any non-page components you need to use either the StaticQuery component or the useStaticQuery hook.

Read more here:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/static-query/

Here is how your code should look like using the useStaticQuery hook

```
import React from "react"

import "../styles/post-repeater.scss"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery, Link } from "gatsby"

export default function PostRepeater() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              path
              title
              date
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `)
   // you might have multiple nodes in which case you must use filter 
   // or find to get node which contains your data. 
   const postQuery = data.allMarkdownRemark.edges[0].node.frontmatter;

   return (
     <>
       {postQuery.map(instance => 
         <div className="post">
           <h2>{instance.title}</h2>
           <span className="datePosted">{instance.date}</span>
           <span className="readTime"></span>
           <p></p>
           <Link to={instance.path}>Read More</Link>
           <hr />
         </div>
       )}
     </>
   )

}
```